# Convergence of sequences in the discrete topology

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm asked to find all the convergent sequences and their limits on $X$ equipped with the discrete topology. My answer is as follows:

The discrete topology is $\mathcal P \left({X}\right)$. If some sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$, then all neighborhoods of $x$ intersect $\{x_n\}$ at some point other than $x$. Since the singleton $\{x\}$ is a neighborhood of $x$ that cannot intersect $\{x_n\}$ at any point other than $x$, then $x$ is not a limit point of any sequence in $X$.

However the correct answer is:

Under the discrete topology a sequence $\{x_n\} ⊆ X$ is convergent, only if $x_n$ stabilizes for $n$ sufficiently big, i.e. there exists an $N$ s.t. for all $n ≥ N$, $x_n = x$ for some $x∈X$; in this case $x_n →x$.

So why is my topological definition of convergence failing me?

Comment: you are confusing two concepts: [limitpoint of set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) and [limitpoint of sequence](https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/real-analysis/limit-points-of-a-sequence.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $x$ when every neighborhhod of $x$ contains every $x_n$ when $n$ is large enough. So, consider the neighborhood $\{x\}$. It contains every $x_n$ when $n$ is large enough. In other words, if $n$ is large enough, then $x_n=x$.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:". If some sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$, then all neighborhoods of $x$ intersect ${x_n}$ at some point other than $x.$"

This is wrong ! Suppose you are right. Then a constant sequence will never converge !

Comment: But isn't that what it means for a point to be a limit point of a set? Or is it that I cannot treat a sequence $\{x_n\}$ as just another set?